# Angular: validating data via $http

Tags: angularjs

I have an Angular directive that allows users to select enter genomic regions, as a row of data. The back-end is Rails and I want to validate the data against the backend.

Within my directive, I have this function to do the validation

```
  function validateTargets(assemblyid,chrom,chrom_start,chrom_end) {
     $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/api/assemblies/' + assemblyid + '/validate/',
        params: {
            chrom: 'chr' + chrom,
            chrom_start: chrom_start,
            chrom_end: chrom_end }
        }).success(function(data) {
            console.log("valid:" + data['validated']);
            return data['validated'];
      });
   }
```

When tested independently this works fine, and returns either **true** or **false**. The user adds a target using edit boxes, and then this code is called

```
scope.addRegion = function() {
      scope.onAddTarget({
        chrom: (scope.coordinates.chrom || null),
        chrom_start: (parseInt(scope.coordinates.start) || null),
        chrom_end: (parseInt(scope.coordinates.end) || null),
        validated: validateTargets(scope.assemblyid,scope.coordinates.chrom,scope.coordinates.start,scope.coordinates.end)
      });
      scope.coordinates = {};
    }
```

What seems to be happening is the validated is set to null or empty at the time the addRegion function is called. Markup on the page shows the fields all populated, except **validated** which is empty or null (ot whatever the correct js term is). The console shows the correct value of the validated true / false from within the validation function.

I assume what is happening is the **addRegion** function completes executing before the **$http** call can complete, and **validated** is undefined / null at that point.

I assume need to somehow wrap it in a promise, but I'm a bit lost on how to do this.

Comment: You can't `return` from an async call - you need to use a callback.

Comment: Can you point out what I need to do ? Isn't the .success the callback?

Comment: Use promises and $resource. You should not use callbacks like that. Validatetargets should return promise and after success you do what you need to do. Return $http({options}).$promise

Comment: Actually $http returns promise automatically, without the property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a callback - given your code you could do the following:

```
function validateTargets(assemblyid,chrom,chrom_start,chrom_end, callback) {
 $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/api/assemblies/' + assemblyid + '/validate/',
    params: {
        chrom: 'chr' + chrom,
        chrom_start: chrom_start,
        chrom_end: chrom_end }
    }).success(function(data) {
        console.log("valid:" + data['validated']);
        callback(data['validated']);
  });
}

scope.addRegion = function() {
  validateTargets(scope.assemblyid,scope.coordinates.chrom,scope.coordinates.start,scope.coordinates.end, function(result) {
      scope.onAddTarget({
        chrom: (scope.coordinates.chrom || null),
        chrom_start: (parseInt(scope.coordinates.start) || null),
        chrom_end: (parseInt(scope.coordinates.end) || null),
        validated: result 
      });
      scope.coordinates = {};
  })
}
```

You need to pass a callback to `validateTargets` so you can use the response of your `http` call elsewhere.

Comment: It looks like this code will work, but am I wrong to think that Angular is supposed to be getting rid of callbacks in favour of promises? Or are either fine?

Comment: Either are fine...you could convert this to use promises just as easily.

Comment: This is giving me an **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier** error **callback(data['validated']);**

Comment: You declare `callback` as a param and pass one in?

Comment: yes I did, just as you described. To the down voter: if you have an alternative solution I would be happy to see it.

Comment: Hmm... does your console.log statement run right before? With the expected output?

Comment: sorry you are right - I had a typo. It's working fine with the callback. Thank you.